# How to find if one of the items in a JSON data is equal to one of the values in an array?

Tags: arrays, json, if-statement, react-native, lodash

I have found and tried out `.includes` to help with this problem. But `.includes` did not work as I intended. It actually did find one item in the JSON that matched the value in the other array, but it only matched **similar values**:

**result_postid array**:

```
[10,22,12,36,45,206]
```

**item.id from JSON data**:

```
[{"id":"5","username":"Mike"},{"id":"13","username":"Tom"},{"id":"28","username":"Jake"},{"id":"136","username":"Josie"},{"id":"400","username":"Bill"},{"id":"538","username":"Sam"}]
```

I tried to figure out why some of the values kept returning `true` when they should be clearly `false`. Then I came to the conclusion that `.includes` was actually taking **`36`** from `result_postid` and matching it with **`136`** in `item.id`. This is how I setup the if statement with `.includes`:

```
{result_postid.includes(item.id) ?
 <Text>True</Text>
 :
 <Text>False</Text>
}
```

This is the result:

```
result_postid | item.id | Result

10 != 5,13,28,136,400,538: False
22 != 5,13,28,136,400,538: False
12 != 5,13,28,136,400,538: False
36 =  5,13,28,136,400,538: True <--- this should be false
45 != 5,13,28,136,400,538: False
206 != 5,13,28,136,400,538: False
```

Then I tried this attempt with Lodash:

```
{_.intersection(item.id, result_postid) ?
<Text>True</Text>
 :
 <Text>False</Text>
}
```

And the results all came `true`, which is not correct:

```
10 = 5,13,28,136,400,538: True
22 = 5,13,28,136,400,538: True
12 = 5,13,28,136,400,538: True
36 = 5,13,28,136,400,538: True 
45 = 5,13,28,136,400,538: True
206 = 5,13,28,136,400,538: True
```

Is it possible to even compare values in an array to JSON data and show whether one value equal each other, if so true? If not, false?

Comment: Are you looping over items? Can you provide a working code snippet  (Ctrl+M) showing this behavior? One issue here is that the ids are `String`s and the values in the array are `Number`s, but either way it would still yield `false` for every item.

Comment: Yes, I am looping over items. I am guessing with the `intersection` if one of the items is true then it marks everything as true @Damon

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the loop you are using, perhaps there is an error there.

Comment: @Damon I mean, I not even sure if it's looping or not. I am pulling data from the database. At first `results_postid` was json data too, but then I used this:  `const result_postid = this.state.data_one.map(function(val) {
     return val.postid;
    }).join(',');` to pull just post id's. Should I do the same with the other JSON data?

Comment: well if you `join` you are turning it into a comma separated string which could be why you are getting a false positive.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you reframe this question with input (JSON) and expected output. Post what you are getting from your database, and what you hope to get as a result by comparing them.

Comment: @Damon Actually, that's why I did use the `join` I needed it to be formatted just like that so that I can compare those two. In PHP, this is easier to do because all I am doing is finding looking for the same values in two different tables. I just can't seem to do it in React Native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get the results you want. Since you are comparing strings to integers your results are not as what you would expect.

```js
var data = [{"id":"5","username":"Mike"},{"id":"13","username":"Tom"},{"id":"28","username":"Jake"},{"id":"136","username":"Josie"},{"id":"400","username":"Bill"},{"id":"538","username":"Sam"}]

var arr = [10,22,12,36,45,206]

console.log(data.map(({id}) => arr.includes(+id)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

By doing the `+id` you are converting the string to number before the next operation.